# How to call onclick function in onCreate without clicking?

Tags: java, android

I want the same function `onclick` to call with `listener` as well as `onCreate`. Is it possible to call `onclick` function on starting app as well as on click at the same time .

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    View view = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    View view1 = findViewById(R.id.fab1);
    view1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: view1.prefromclick() ?

Comment: why not make a function called clicked(); and have whatever you want inside it, then call the function from onCreate, onClick and so on..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During `onCreate()`, just call: `onClick(null);`